# Can a Slack bot re-share a file that was shared with it?

Tags: slack-api

Context of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- User shares a file with the bot
- Other users interact with the bot via a dialog
- The bot shares the original file to the other users

For example, we want to share a file to the bot that contains this week's cafeteria menu. Each time users would interact with the bot in a certain way, it would share the cafeteria menu with them so that they can consult it.

I've tried calling `files.share` method but bots can't perform this action (get invalid token type error).

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this currently. I've tried link unfurling in the message body but that only works if the file itself was already shared to the user. If not, the link simply won't unfurl and clicking it will fail.

The bot can perform a `files.upload` call and re-upload the contents of the file to each user individually. This seems incredibly wasteful but appears to be the only way to work currently.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

The reason your bot can not use [`file.share`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/files.share.md) is that this is an undocumented API method and you need a legacy token to use it. No other token (user token, bot token) will work, because it requires the `post` scope, which only exists for legacy token.

**Approach A: Legacy Token**

So one approach would be to use a legacy token with your bot, which you can create [here](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) for your current workspace. That should work nicely if your Slack app is only used on your "own" Slack workspace where you can create and use a legacy token.

**Approach B: File Mention**

Another approach is to use the mention feature in messages to share a file. This works by sending the private link (`url_private` property) of an already shared file in a message to a new channel. This will automatically re-share the file in that channel. I believe this only works with files that how been previously shares in a public channel and can therefore be re-shared. Be aware though that the file mention feature is [currently being reworked](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2018-05-file-threads-soon-tread), so this behavior might change.

Example:

```
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=TOKEN&channel=CHANNEL&as_user=true&text=URL_PRIVATE
```

For more details see the Slack tutorial [Storing, retrieving, and modifying file uploads](http://Storing,%20retrieving,%20and%20modifying%20file%20uploads).

**Approach C: External File / image file**

If you host your file externally or create a public URL for a file uploaded to Slack you can share it in every channel by just adding the URL to a message. Slack will automatically unfurl it and therefore share it to the user in any channel. This is different to Approach B, because its not a file mention and requires a public URL. You get the public URL of an uploaded file by calling [`files.sharedPublicURL`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL).

Comment: This answer wins the bounty even though it technically doesn't fit the requirements since there really isn't a better way to do this at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, you can do like this :

- you share a file with your bot
- you retrieve the file shared ID, so his url_private property (cf https://api.slack.com/types/file#authentication)
- you then donwload the file
- you can then re-share it several times later (without re-uploading to each user)...

Comment: No, you cannot use url_private unless the user you are sharing it to also has access to the file. Since the file was only previously shared with the bot, the other users don't have access.